# Finding a condition for compatibility of a given system of linear equations with restrcitions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the following system of linear equations $$5x+y+z+3w=a, 8x+3y+z+2w=2-a ~~~~(*) $$
with the following restriction $$ x,y,z,w\geq 0 ~~~~(**)$$

I want to find all possible values of $a$ so that there is a solution satisfying $(*)$ and $(**)$.

Clearly without $(**)$, the system $(*)$ is compatible for all $a$. But if we have $(**)$, we must have $a\geq 0$ and $2-a\geq 0$, so $0\leq a\leq 2$. Now I am only left to check that $(*)$ has a solution satisfying $(**)$ if $a\in [0,2]$, but I have no idea for this. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(*)$ is equivalent to
$$z=-14x-7y+6-5a,\quad w=3x+2y-2+2a.$$
Let $\alpha:=2-2a$ and $\beta:=6-5a.$

The numbers $z,w$ as above are both $\ge0$ iff
$3x+2y\ge\alpha$ and $14x+7y\le\beta,$ i.e. $y\ge\frac{\alpha-3x}2$ and $y\le\frac{\beta-14x}7.$

The existence of a $y\ge0$ satisfying both conditions is equivalent to $\frac{\alpha-3x}2\le\frac{\beta-14x}7$ and $0\le\frac{\beta-14x}7,$ i.e. $\beta\ge14x$ and $2\beta-7\alpha\ge7x.$

Finally, the existence of an $x\ge0$ satisfying these two latter conditions is equivalent to $\beta\ge0$ and $2\beta-7\alpha\ge0,$ i.e.
$$\frac12\le a\le\frac65.$$
There is no need to check anything since we reasoned by equivalences. However, here is a solution for any such $a$:
$$x=z=0,\quad y=\frac{6-5a}7,\quad w=\frac{4a-2}7.$$